# How to compute 2D log-chromaticity?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, colors

My goal is to remove shadows from image. I use C++ and OpenCV. Sure I lack enough math background and not being native English speaker makes everything harder to understand.

After reading different approaches to remove shadows I found method which should work for me but it relies on something they call "**2D chromaticity**" and "**2D log-chromaticity space**" but even this term seems to be inconsistent in different sources. Many papers on topic, few are listed here:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/LBMV09/Papers/finlayson-eccv-04.pdf
http://www2.cmp.uea.ac.uk/Research/compvis/Papers/DrewFinHor_ICCV03.pdf
http://www.cvc.uab.es/adas/publications/alvarez_2008.pdf
http://ivrgwww.epfl.ch/alumni/fredemba/papers/FFICPR06.pdf

I teared Google into strips by searching right words and explanations. Best I found is [Illumination invariant image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922467/illumination-invariant-image) which did not help me much.

I tried to repeat formula *log(G/R)*, *log(B/R)* described in first paper, page 3 to get figures similar to 2b.

[image]

As input I used http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Gretag-Macbeth_ColorChecker.jpg

Output I get is 
[image: log-chromacity]

My source code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  Mat src;

  src = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  if( !src.data )
    { return -1; }

  Mat image( 600, 600, CV_8UC3, Scalar(127,127,127) );

  int cn = src.channels();
  uint8_t* pixelPtr = (uint8_t*)src.data;

  for(int i=0 ; i< src.rows;i++) {
      for(int j=0 ; j< src.cols;j++) {
          Scalar_<uint8_t> bgrPixel;
          bgrPixel.val[0] = pixelPtr[i*src.cols*cn + j*cn + 0]; // B
          bgrPixel.val[1] = pixelPtr[i*src.cols*cn + j*cn + 1]; // G
          bgrPixel.val[2] = pixelPtr[i*src.cols*cn + j*cn + 2]; // R
          if(bgrPixel.val[2] !=0 ) { // avoid division by zero
              float a= image.cols/2+50*(log((float)bgrPixel.val[0] / (float)bgrPixel.val[2])) ;
              float b= image.rows/2+50*(log((float)bgrPixel.val[1] / (float)bgrPixel.val[2])) ;
              if(!isinf(a) && !isinf(b))
                  image.at<Vec3b>(a,b)=Vec3b(255,2,3);
          }
      }
  }

  imshow("log-chroma", image );
  imwrite("log-chroma.png", image );
  waitKey(0);
```

}

What I am missing or misunderstand?

Comment: Did you fix it eventually?

Comment: Sorry, do not remember.

Comment: You don't remember or you don't want to remember?

Comment: Really, do not remember. No reason to hide anything.

Answer (score 1):

By reading the paper [Recovery of Chromaticity Image Free from Shadows via Illumination Invariance](http://www2.cmp.uea.ac.uk/Research/compvis/Papers/DrewFinHor_ICCV03.pdf) that you've posted, and your code, I guess the problem is that your coordinate system (X/Y axis) are linear while in the paper the coordinate system are log(R/G) by log(B/G).

Comment: Takes time to verify this very interesting answer in actual code (I am busy with something else at moment). Thanks anyway!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I can figure. Reading through this:

http://www2.cmp.uea.ac.uk/Research/compvis/Papers/DrewFinHor_ICCV03.pdf

I came across the sentence:

> *"Fig. 2(a) shows log-chromaticities for the 24 surfaces of a Macbeth ColorChecker Chart, (**the six neutral patches all belong to the same
>   cluster**). If we now **vary the lighting** and **plot median values
>   for each patch**, we see the curves in Fig. 2(b)."*

If you look closely at the log-chromaticity plot, you see 19 blobs, corresponding to each of the 18 colors in the Macbeth chart, plus the sum of all the 6 grayscale targets in the bottom row:

Explanation of Log Chromaticities

[Explanation of Log Chromaticities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLxlX.png)

With 1 picture, we can only get 1 point of each blob: We take the median value **inside each target** and plot it. To get plot from the paper, we would have to create multiple images with different lighting. We might be able to do this by varying the temperature of the image in an image editor.

For now, I just looked at the color patches in the original image and plotted the points:

**Input:**

[Color Patches Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbfuG.png)

**Output:**

[Log Chromaticity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIR91.png)

The graph dots are not all in the same place as the paper, but I figure it's fairly close. Would someone please check my work to see if this makes sense?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I changed my response into an answer. I believe this comes very close to answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

In that OpenCV code I got a `"undefined Identifier error"` for the function `ifinf()` and I solved it by replacing it with `_finite()`. That might be the issue with the Visual studio version.

```
if(!isinf(a) && !isinf(b)) ----> if(_finite(a) && _finite(b))
```

Include this header:

```
#include<float.h>
```

Comment: Thank You. But this is not an answer to question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30343927)