# How to Plot Image Log-Chromaticity Plot in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, colors, rgb

I am trying to create a 2D log chromaticity plot in python with OpenCV. The same question was asked here

[How to compute 2D log-chromaticity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282856/how-to-compute-2d-log-chromaticity)

but it was never answered.

(**ASIDE:** A guess was made that the axes must be log instead of linear, but this is incorrect as the paper uses negative coordinates, and log axes cannot be negative. Also, I was desparate and tried `plt.xscale('log')` and `plt.yscale('log')`, but it didn't work).

This work is based off this paper:

https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~mark/ftp/Eccv04/

*(I re-mention it below)*

**My Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = r'.\path\to\root'
root = r'my_img.jpg'

if __name__ == '__main__':

    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(root, fl))

    cv2.imshow('Original', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    b, g, r = cv2.split(img)

    img_sum = np.sum(img, axis = 2) # NOTE: This dtype will be uint32.
                                    #       Each channel can be up to
                                    #       255 (dtype = uint8), but
                                    #       since uint8 can only go up
                                    #       to 255, sum naturally uint32

    # "Normalized" channels
    # NOTE: np.ma is the masked array library. It automatically masks
    #       inf and nan answers from result

    n_r = np.ma.divide(1.*r, g)
    n_b = np.ma.divide(1.*b, g)

    log_rg = np.ma.log( n_r )
    log_bg = np.ma.log( n_b )

    plt.scatter(l_rg, l_bg, s = 2)
    plt.xlabel('Log(R/G)')
    plt.ylabel('Log(B/G)')
    plt.title('2D Log Chromaticity')
    plt.show()
```

**Input:**

[Color Checker Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4ZgS.png)

**Result:**

[My Log Chromaticity Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0oPr.png)

**Expected Result:**

[Finlayson Log Chromaticity Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oISkS.png)

The expected result was taken from this paper ("Intrinsic Images by Entropy Minimization", by: Finlayson, G., et. al.):

https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~mark/ftp/Eccv04/

*(Paper also mentioned above)*

**Can you help me please?!**

Comment: You should probably rephrase the title... this way it's right now really hints at logging, rather than plotting a chart with a logarithmic scale (or maybe not even that, as I read further in).

Comment: I will certainly rephrase the title. Do you have any suggestions for solving this problem?

Comment: Nope (I'm definitely out of my depth here), although some quick digging through papers trying to figure out what that plot actually is led me to [this](http://www2.cmp.uea.ac.uk/Research/compvis/Papers/FinHor_JOSA01.pdf)

Comment: Would you mind forwarding this out to anyone you know? I am desparate for an answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the closest I can figure. Reading through this:

http://www2.cmp.uea.ac.uk/Research/compvis/Papers/DrewFinHor_ICCV03.pdf

I came across the sentence:

> *"Fig. 2(a) shows log-chromaticities for the 24 surfaces of a Macbeth ColorChecker Chart, (**the six neutral patches all belong to the same
>   cluster**). If we now **vary the lighting** and **plot median values
>   for each patch**, we see the curves in Fig. 2(b)."*

If you look closely at the log-chromaticity plot, you see 19 blobs, corresponding to each of the 18 colors in the Macbeth chart, plus the sum of all the 6 grayscale targets in the bottom row:

Explanation of Log Chromaticities

[image]

With 1 picture, we can only get 1 point of each blob: We take the median value **inside each target** and plot it. To get plot from the paper, we would have to create multiple images with different lighting. We might be able to do this by varying the temperature of the image in an image editor.

For now, I just looked at the color patches in the original image and plotted the points:

**Input:**

[image: Color Patches Used]

**Output:**

[image: Log Chromaticity]

The graph dots are not all in the same place as the paper, but I figure it's fairly close. Would someone please check my work to see if this makes sense?